# Catching Exceptions on Python Flask RestPlus

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I am struggling with finding a way to return a response when a call to one of my APIs does not return any result. I am using flask_restplus, and tried to use the @api.errorhandler annotation with no success and then I resorted to try a plain try/except block in my class.

In this particular issue, I am trying to call the endpoint, where the GUID is a non-existent user in the database.

```
http://localhost:5000/api/users/b3d8e86b-f2ad-4b6a-b768-e7adc1d94ced
```

The user end point has been defined as following:

```
import logging

from flask import Response
from flask_restplus import Resource, fields
from neomodel.core import DoesNotExist

from app.api.restplus import api
from app.models import User

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

ns = api.namespace('users', description='Users')

user = api.model('user', {
    'id': fields.Integer(readOnly=True, description='The internal id of of a user'),
    'user_id': fields.String(required=True, description='The user unique identifier')}
)

@ns.route('/')
@api.response(404, 'Users not found.')
class UsersList(Resource):

    @api.marshal_list_with(user)
    def get(self):
        """
        Returns a list of all users
        :return: list_of_users
        """
        try:
            users = User.nodes
            list_of_users = list(users)
            return list_of_users
    #        return json.dumps(dict(users = [user.serialize for user in list_of_users]))
        except DoesNotExist:
            return Response(('{"No Content": "No user nodes found"}'), status = 200, mimetype = 'application/json')


@ns.route('/<string:user_id>')
class UserItem(Resource):

   @api.marshal_with(user)
   def get(self, user_id):
        """
        Returns a user with the given user_id
        :param id: user_id
        :return: user
        """
        try:
            user = User.nodes.get(user_id=user_id)
            return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'Could not locate a user with the user_id provided.'}, 404)
```

My initialization is done in app/**init**.py:

```
import logging.config
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from neomodel import clear_neo4j_database
from neomodel import db

from app.config import Configuration
from app.web_app.routes import webapp_mod
from app.data_loader.routes import dataloader_mod
from app.utilities import prepare_rerun
from app.api.endpoints.users import ns as users_namespace
from app.api.endpoints.sessions import ns as sessions_namespace
from app.api.endpoints.browsers import ns as browsers_namespace
from app.api.endpoints.os import ns as os_namespace
from app.api.endpoints.applications import ns as applications_namespace
from app.api.endpoints.tenants import ns as tenants_namepspace
from app.api.endpoints.devices import  ns as devices_namespace
from app.api.endpoints.environments import ns as environments_namespace

from app.api.restplus import api
from os import path


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)
app.register_blueprint(dataloader_mod, url_prefix='/data_loader')
log_file_path = path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), 'logging.conf')
logging.config.fileConfig(log_file_path)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api.init_app(blueprint)
api.add_namespace(users_namespace)
api.add_namespace(sessions_namespace)
api.add_namespace(browsers_namespace)
api.add_namespace(applications_namespace)
api.add_namespace(tenants_namepspace)
api.add_namespace(devices_namespace)
api.add_namespace(os_namespace)
api.add_namespace(environments_namespace)
```

The resplus.py module where I define the api at this point has just the definition of the api object, but I had tried to follow some examples online and define in it methods to handle the exceptions through the annotations in the users object.

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from neomodel.core import DoesNotExist

api = Api(version='1.0', title='Users Activity Log',
          description='An API to retreive information about users'' activities in Infor Ming.le')
```

However when I make the call, instead of getting a JSON response with the message and 404 code, I am getting:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "user_id": null
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I experience the same error. Have you already found a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I am a little late to help *you* but I might help other people having the same problem:

The thing is, although you have an other return code (and you have an error) flask still tries to use `@marshal_with(user)`. It might be a little bit confusing at first.

If you look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364555/how-to-return-a-response-with-multiple-marshal-with-in-flask-restplus/61603411#61603411) you can see how to return multiple answer types without loosing the swagger functionality plus you still got the marshalling. This is a bit more versatile than the standard `@marshal_with`.

There are other ways of achieving similar results for errors: E.g. you could use the abort() function (which might be more logical in some cases).

So in other words your code transformed would look somehow like this:

```
import logging

from flask import Response
from flask_restplus import Resource, fields, marshal
from neomodel.core import DoesNotExist

from app.api.restplus import api
from app.models import User

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

ns = api.namespace('users', description='Users')

user = api.model('user', {
    'id': fields.Integer(readOnly=True, description='The internal id of of a user'),
    'user_id': fields.String(required=True, description='The user unique identifier')}
)

@ns.route('/')
@api.response(404, 'Users not found.')
class UsersList(Resource):

    @api.response(model=user, code=200)
    @api.response(404, 'Users not found.')
    def get(self):
        """
        Returns a list of all users
        :return: list_of_users
        """
        try:
            users = User.nodes
            list_of_users = list(users)
            return marshal(list_of_users)
        except DoesNotExist:
            return {"No Content": "No user nodes found"}, 404


@ns.route('/<string:user_id>')
class UserItem(Resource):

   @api.response(model=user, code=200)
   @api.response(code=404, 'Users not found.')
   def get(self, user_id):
        """
        Returns a user with the given user_id
        :param id: user_id
        :return: user
        """
        try:
            user = User.nodes.get(user_id=user_id)
            return marshal(user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return {'message': 'Could not locate a user with the user_id provided.'}, 404

# More Endpoints - I hope this did the job...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
from flask_restplus import abort
abort(400, custom='value')
```

To abort and through errors

or

```py
namespace.abort(400, "An error occured")
```

Answer (score -1):

This is likely no longer relevant as your question is from quite a while ago, but I came across this as I was searching around for flask-restplus exception handling best practices. I don't think your problem is with flask-restplus' exception handling. It sounds like your User class is not raising a DoesNotExist exception when the user doesn't exist. Did you verify whether you're even hitting the Except: block?

Anyhow, once you verify that you are indeed raising the DoesNotExist exception, you can register an errorhandler for that exception in your **init.py** like this:

```
@api.errorhandler(DoesNotExist)
def handle_user_does_not_exist_error(error):
    return ({'message': 'Could not locate a user with the user_id provided.'}, 404)
```

Comment: This problem still persists.