# How to return a response with multiple marshal_with() in flask_restplus?

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

Following is `flask_restplus` response call for PUT verb

```
@api.doc('update a franchise by id')
    @api.expect(create_item_fields, validate=True)
    @api.marshal_with(success_fields)
    def put(self, fid):
        franchise = FranchiseModel.query.filter_by(id=fid).first()
        if franchise:
            is_success, result = FranchiseModel.update_franchise(
                franchise, api.payload)
            if is_success:
                return {'success': True, 'message': 'Franchise has been updated', 'data': result}, 200
            else:
                raise CouldNotUpdateFranchise(str(result))

@api.errorhandler(CouldNotUpdateFranchise)
    @api.marshal_with(error_fields)
    def return_error(error):
        return {'success': False, 'message': str(error)}, 400
```

I'm making use of the `@api.errorhandler` But I don't know how to return multiple response format with `marshal_with`

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Ok old answer just lists it as a valid response in Swagger.

But with this article https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/559 I still got the solution:

```
from flask_restplus import marshal
# I call API 'foo' and my Namespace 'bar'
another = foo.model('For 200', {'Another': fields.Integer()})
success = foo.model('For 201', {'Success': fields.Integer()})

@bar.route('/test/<int:id>')
class Test(Resource):
    @bar.response(model=another, code=200)
    @bar.response(model=success, code=201)
    def get(self, id):
        if id == 200:
             return marshal({'Another': 200}, another), 200
        elif id == 201:
             return marshal({'Success': 201}, success), 201
```

Comment: I hope you get what I wanted to say here... It is a little late around here...

Comment: Though it's been a while, I must say this works and has actually helped me, even now using `flask-restx`, since `flask-restplus` is no longer maintained.

Comment: Yes I was actually working with flask-restx as well but when I wrote this answer it worked for both platforms :)